# Where should I put the upload function - Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm reading and trying to apply [this article about File Uploads](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html), but there is a problem. It's said that this:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $document->upload();

    $em->persist($document);
    $em->flush();

    $this->redirect(...);
}
```

should go in a Controller and here is the definition of the `upload` function

```
public function upload()
{
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    // we use the original file name here but you should
    // sanitize it at least to avoid any security issues

    // move takes the target directory and then the target filename to move to
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->file->getClientOriginalName());

    // set the path property to the filename where you'ved saved the file
    $this->path = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();

    // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
    $this->file = null;
}
```

But where should I put this? I tried in the controller, above the action which calls it and an error occures - `Fatal error: Call to undefined method...` I also tried to put it in a different class and file and to add its namespace with use, but the error stays.
Could you please show me where is the mistake? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully at the code, you will see that upload is called as a function of the document object:

```
$document->upload();
```

So, that is where it should go, in your Document entity class

Comment: Sometimes I'm wondering if I can be more stupid... Thank you very much!